# What's causing this ramp on a video signal?

Tags: video, oscilloscope

See this image, it's a composite video signal on my scope.

[image: Scope shot]

As can be seen the dc offset of the signal is varying with time; it also varies with brightness in the scene.

I am plugging the signal from a composite video signal directly into my scope, however the cable is also spliced and goes to my computer's TV card. Without the TV card attached I do not see this. Now I would like to be able to debug my signal using the TV card, but it seems to be interfering (maybe it's loading the signal too much) - what could be causing this? I have another card I'm going to try but I'm not hopeful. Apart from buffering the signal using expensive video buffer amps, what can I try?

Comment: Charging of caps?

Comment: But *what* cap, and why does it do it every cycle?

Comment: can you put the scope in a low impedance input mode? try it that way. most RF circuits expect a termination resistance like 50 or 75 ohms. (i think 75 ohms is the common value for video). if the scope doesn't have it built in, you could put a non-inductive resistor across the signal. the video card input ought to have that kind of impedance but you never know.

Comment: I don't have a 75 ohm termination option on the scope, but I do have two 150 ohm resistors in parallel. I'll try it.

Comment: Hmm I removed my resistors (as originally present) and it still swings, though the output voltage is much higher and there is some kind of weird noise on the signal.

Comment: 75 ohms for your coax cable, just as a note to those that are interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the source is AC coupled ( and shouldn't be)

you've got dc offset shifting with picture brightness. Video should be DC coupled and terminated into 75ohms. If that sounds like something that your wouldn't string across a room, congratulations; it was never designed to. I remember reading that in-studio distribution was never raw analog video. So check the source path for a cap.

Unless it's just a really bad ground connection (high resistance) ;and the ground is elevating with brightness, which is consistent with that. So check the return path resistance too.

Analog video; it's frustrating because it was never intended to go very far as a baseband signal.

Comment: Many video devices are AC coupled on the inputs and outputs; it might be nice if that weren't the case, but in practice unless one knows one will only be accepting signals from devices with DC-coupled inputs, one has to accept AC-coupled signals. Further, in many cases, if one will have to deal with AC-coupled signals, it's often helpful to AC-couple one's own input stage.  See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11334/dc-restoration-of-a-video-signal for more info.